# Xcode6: Parse issue where code contains *)

Tags: ios, parsing, xcode6

In Xcode7,everything is ok.
But i want to test app in IOS7.1. So i use Xcode6.1.
But there are many parse issues:

[image]

```
- (instancetype)initWithPreView:(UIView*)preView
                ArrayObjectType:(NSArray*)arrayBarCodeType
                       cropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
                        success:(void(^)(NSArray<LBXScanResult*> *array))blockScanResult;
```

this line has issue.

How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you have look the picture? My XCode6 really has parse issues.

Comment: why do you have the * after the `LBXScanResut` the * before `array` already tells it is a pointer and the Protocol information usually comes without that pointer marker?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't understand the *Generics* as shown here:

```
NSArray<LBXScanResult*> *array
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no way around this, other than to modify the source code to:

```
NSArray *array
```

However if you are able to test on a device, rather than use a simulator, there is no reason why you have to change to Xcode 6 at all; simply stay on Xcode 7.  If you don't have access to a device then you are stuck, I'm afraid, and you cannot support iOS 7.1 with that source code.

Comment: That's the correct solution, buy an iOS 7 device. You should get an iPhone 4 on eBay for £50.

Comment: I still don't know why my codes can not work on Xcode6.

Comment: I get it! It is to say the Xcode6 don't support Generics. Thank you!